# How do I get org icalendar export to *not* include the date in the calendar item summary?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I write my org-mode entries like this:

```
*** Some Event <2015-10-11 Sun 18:30-19:30>

    Some description
```

icalendar export used to automatically use "Some Event" as the icalendar item's SUMMARY, but now (somewhere between versions 7 and 8.2.10) it uses all of "Some Event <2015-10-11 Sun 18:30-19:30>" as the SUMMARY string, which is just wrong (it knows that last part is a date and uses it to create the icalendar .

The only way I have found to fix this is to create a SUMMARY property, like so:

```
*** Some Event <2015-10-11 Sun 18:30-19:30>
    :PROPERTIES:
    :SUMMARY:  Some Event
    :END:
    Some description
```

This is, however, awful for maintenance, because now I have to write and/or edit "Some Event" in two places.

Is there a way to have the date automatically excluded from the summary?

Comment: If it's OK to include the timestamp in the DESCRIPTION field, then you can move it to the line after the headline. The agenda recognizes it in either place. OTOH, if you don't want it in the DESCRIPTION field either, then filtering is indicated as shown in @Robert's answer.

Answer (score 1):

One, albeit not perfect, option would be to [filter](https://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-Export-Configuration.html) the heading text using a function like this:

```lisp
(defun my-filter-timestamps (text backend info)
  "Remove timestamps from headings."
  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'icalendar)
    (replace-regexp-in-string org-stamp-time-of-day-regexp "" text)))

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-headline-functions
             'my-filter-timestamps)
```

Unfortunately, for time ranges a "--" remains but that's could likely be fixed by a more sophisticated regex.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Robert's answer, I had to make a few edits to make it work for me, and additionally with use-package (placing it in a :config block).

```
;; change ical export, remove timestamp with regex
(require 'ox-latex)

(defun my-filter-timestamps (text backend info)
    "Remove timestamps from headings."
    (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'icalendar)
      (replace-regexp-in-string "<[0-9]\\{4\\}-[0-9]\\{2\\}-[0-9]\\{2\\}[^>]*>" " " text)))  

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-headline-functions
               'my-filter-timestamps)
```

And with my version I am not getting any "--" remaining. It looks great for me now in ical, but the export is much much slower. Glacial.